# can't create FIrebase realtime-database

Tags: firebase

I'm just looking into firebase, after logging in with my google account and creating a project I cannot create a real-time database in the dashboard/console, the database permission dialog appears and clicking ok give a 500 error in the console.

health check says the service is up, and no detail error information is available is there another way to do this, maybe a cli tool or legacy dashboard that still works?

Comment: *firebaser here* That sounds broken. Are there any details about the error showing in the JavaScript console? Can you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting?

Comment: thanks I though it must just be an outage but wanted to check if there was something obvious I might be missing outside of clicking the create button. I've submitted a bug report and will just have to wait I guess. This is my first look evaluating for work so not a great first impression if it is an outage and not my mistake.

Comment: Sorry that you're hitting this. I'm not sure what's going on yet, and we haven't seen any reports like yours until *very* recently. Can you confirm for me what database you are trying to create? There are two databases in Firebase: Realtime Database, and Cloud Firestore, and the creation path is completely different between them.

Comment: Realtime Database, I'm in my project in the real-time database section there's a cta with "create database" which opens the failing dialog

Comment: Darn... the other report was for Firestore, hence the double check. Our support team is working with the engineers on fixing whatever caused this (it seems permission related). This was definitely a mistake on our side. So sorry to give you such a lousy impression on your first try with Firebase. Thanks for the report though , and I'll hope you'll give us another chance once we fix this problem.

Comment: it happens, thanks for reaching out, I'll keep the outage out of my report ;)

Comment: Thanks. ;-) The problem should be solved now, so please let me know if you see lingering issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There was a problem with creating Firestore and Realtime Databases on newly created Firebase projects for the past few hours. Existing projects and databases were not affected, and no data was lost.

The problem has been solved now.

Comment: Thanks Frank, it was actually amazing to post this question, get and answer and a resolution from someone actually at Firebase so quickly, awesome!